# Convert xPath into CSS selector

Tags: css, xpath

Is there a way to convert these to a CSS selectors?

1) '//form//div[contains(@class,"myclass")]'

2) '//div[contains(@class,"myclass")]//input[@type="submit"]'

3) './/label[(substring(./@for, ((string-length(./@for) - string-length('_state')) + 1)) = '_state')]'

Comment: Exactly these three? Or you need an general approach?

Comment: https://ghostinspector.com/docs/css-xpath-conversion/ this might help. Unless you're looking to automate it.

Comment: Exactly these and a general approach for more later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the css for the first 2.

'//form//div[contains(@class,"myclass")]'

> form div[class*='myclass']

'//div[contains(@class,"myclass")]//input[@type="submit"]'

> div[class*='myclass'] input[type='submit']

'.//label[(substring(./@for, ((string-length(./@for) - string-length('_state')) + 1)) = '_state')]'

> label[for $='_state']

Comment: These work. Thank you.  And the link above was very helpful too